# In Jenkins is it possible to make "Pull Request" tab to be shown by default (instead of Branches)?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

In Jenkins, we have a job created from a multibranch pipeline, we do all the actions from a pull request, so we want to show only the pull requests instead of both branches and pull requests, is there any way to achieve this?

We want to show only the pull requests tab:

[image: img]

Comment: We have this same question and would love if the Branches option were not shown if the job is configured only for pull requests.